# sendkeys not working on a field that is not of type 'file' - selenium with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate a field with Selenium and JavaScript, which I must send a file from my screen in the test. However, the field to send the file is not of type "File" and the sendkeys() method is not working. Below my HTML:

```
xpath=//button\[@id='id-ff3923ce-1732-4337-911e-75e0d718fc8a-36-notescontrol-attachment_action'\]/span
```

this is the element I should send the file to. it's a button of sorts. I don't know how to solve this, can someone help me?

I tried to run the code below but the error was:

```
erro  ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.248)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\Users\SRV_GHQ_ITSEngQA\Desktop\mocha_selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:524:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\SRV_GHQ_ITSEngQA\Desktop\mocha_selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:601:13)
    at Executor.execute (C:\Users\SRV_GHQ_ITSEngQA\Desktop\mocha_selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:529:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async thenableWebDriverProxy.execute (C:\Users\SRV_GHQ_ITSEngQA\Desktop\mocha_selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:745:17)
    at async GrPage.file (C:\Users\SRV_GHQ_ITSEngQA\Desktop\mocha_selenium\pageobjects\Grpage.js:120:7)
    at async Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SRV_GHQ_ITSEngQA\Desktop\mocha_selenium\test\GRTest.js:85:9) {
  remoteStacktrace: 'Backtrace:\n' +
```

```
     async file(){

      try {
            
      const filePath = '../resources/qa.jpg';  
      let  fileInput = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(".Attach-symbol")));

      await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(fileInput), 5000);
      await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(fileInput), 5000);

      await fileInput.sendKeys(filePath);


          } catch (error) {
            console.log("erro ", error)
          }
          
      }
```